# Resfreshing my Partial in Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

So I have a Partial view that loads in with:

```
@Html.Partial("_partial", Model, new ViewDataDictionary { { "DisplayCheckbox", true } })
```

Within that `_partial` page is a loop that looks like this

```
@foreach (var w in Model.WeekEndingDateRange)
{
    <th>@w.WeekEndingDate.FormatDate()</th>
}
```

which creates table headers for a jquery tinytable (that is later populated with data in my view).

The problem I'm having is that the `Model.WeekEndingDateRange` can change. When the user presses a button to filter results shown on the table, it makes an ajax call to my controller that looks like this

```
function filterResults(){
    //do some stuff like creating "model"

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "@Url.Action("FilterTable", "Report")",
        data: model
    })
    .done(function (data) {
        //continue on to populate table data
```

So when the ajax call finishes I can make a call like:

```
data.WeekEndingDateRange
```

to grab the list which I want the partial to loop through. This will create (size of the `data.WeekEndingDateRange` list) amount of headers for the table.

Therefore I need a way for the partial to **not** grab **Model.WeekEndingDateRange** but instead to grab **data.WeekEndingDateRange**. This way, before the table is filtered, the partial will create no headers (because no information is populated in the table) and as soon as the user filters their results, the table will create a new header for each element in **data.WeekEndingDateRange**.

I've already tried doing:

```
@Html.Partial("_ProjectAllocationReport", data, new ViewDataDictionary { { "DisplayCheckbox", true } })')
```

after my ajax call, but this won't work because data is out of scope.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you just leverage your view. You actually **DO** want the partial to grab **Model.WeekEndingDateRange**. The problem is that your not updating the Model's WeekEndingDateRange.

So your ajax call would be something like

```
function filterResults()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "",
        data: model,
        datatype: "html"
    }).done(function(html)
    {
        $("HeaderElementHere").html(html);
    });
}
```

And in your controller, do

```
Model.WeekEndingDateRange = data.WeekEndingDateRange
@Html.Partial("_partial", Model, new ViewDataDictionary { { "DisplayCheckbox", true } })
```

All you are really wanting to do is pass up some end date that your View uses for it's loop to generate your HTML and then pass that back down in the ajax call to be put into your page.